# jboss 7 :Unable to login into web console with my credentials

Tags: jboss

I am using Windows 7 and JBoss as a windows service I just added a user as shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

I get to the following access page :

[image]

I entered the exact credentials that I set up and it's not accepting the login credentials which is strange. Does anyone know the problem?

Here is my `mgmt-users.properties` file contents

```
#
# Properties declaration of users for the realm 'ManagementRealm' which is the default realm
# for new AS 7.1 installations. Further authentication mechanism can be configured
# as part of the <management /> in standalone.xml.
#
# Users can be added to this properties file at any time, updates after the server has started
# will be automatically detected.
#
# By default the properties realm expects the entries to be in the format: -
# username=HEX( MD5( username ':' realm ':' password))
#
# A utility script is provided which can be executed from the bin folder to add the users: -
# - Linux
#  bin/add-user.sh
#
# - Windows
#  bin\add-user.bat

# The following illustrates how an admin user could be defined, this
# is for illustration only and does not correspond to a usable password.
#
#admin=2a0923285184943425d1f53ddd58ec7a
i2b2demo=4120965c8ffaac69b979742774a517d3
```

Comment: Which version of JBoss is this?

Comment: It's Jboss 7.1.1 version.